# Header when download file using phpword

Tags: php, css, laravel

Can you tell me what is wrong with my headers? My download work fine. I use PHPWord library but I think the problem is the header.

```
<?php
    require_once 'PHPWord.php';
    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();

    $section = $PHPWord->createSection();
    $wordText = utf8_encode($_REQUEST['TEXT']);

    $section->addText($wordText);

    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
    //$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
    $path = 'tmp/kikou2.docx';
    $objWriter->save($path);

    //download code
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;  filename='.$path);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
    flush();
    readfile($path);
    unlink($path);
    exit(); 


?>
```

After download, I get the file'content like this:

PK########tJWF90�G�;##&<######word/media/section_image1.png<�#p&�#/�Ķm�N�ض��m��ض��m��nl����7U]3�5�5�}�#5'JIA####### HK��## #�5Ph�z`J?J�wr��v###���@��#�##b�����g�e�E�/Mw��gS�l��#��-�����2�#\#�"n5��G�W�G�|#X+#    \��B��Ks��#�#@��[��y�7�����j��Êh�|#BA�^#49j�[��Gv�#��#��#�#z>짙C���v`)���_��#��

Answer (score 0):

Just using this header should work

```
header('Content-Type: application/msword'); // for .doc files
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); // for .docx files
```

first check with the above headers. The file should be readable. If it's not then there's something wrong with PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter()

Also the Laravel way of doing this would be:

```
$objWriter->save($path);

$response = Response::make(Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::get($path), 200);
$response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;  filename='.$path);
$response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response->header('Expires', 0);
$response->header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$response->header('Pragma', 'public');
$response->header('Content-Length', filesize($path));

return $response;
```

Comment: I tried to follow all your solutions above, but the file's content still like before. Yes I'm using Laravel .

Comment: If you're getting hieroglyphics  when just the header "header('Content-Type: application/msword');" was used your file is probably corrupted. As i said check the PHPWord_IOFactory documentation.